# Shared connection between functions

Tags: database, testing, mysqli, connection, phpunit

I have a question regarding shared connections. I have tried for many weeks to solve this problem and have tried many different things like PDO connection, getConnetion you name it. But I still don't get it to work. What I want to do is to create a connection to my database **ONCE** and then not have to declare it again. In PHPUnit you have the setUp and tearDown functions that I am acquainted with. Basically I would like to declare the database connection in the setUp so that before each test there will be a connection to the database which is needed to execute the unit-tests. At the moment I am forced to declare a new connection to the database within each function to get it to work. Otherwise I get error messages stating that I have an "undefined variable $mysqli" wihtin each function or it may say "call to a member function query() on a non-object". This is my code:

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';

class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

protected function setUp(){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db');

public function testCheckbrute(){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db');

$LessThanFive = checkbrute('200', $mysqli);
$this->assertFalse($LessThanFive);

$FiveFailedLogins = checkbrute('201', $mysqli);
$this->assertTrue($FiveFailedLogins);
}

public function testLogin(){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db');
$AccountIsLockedFalse = Login("xxxx","xxxx", $mysqli);
$this->assertFalse($AccountIsLockedFalse);

$NoUserExists = Login("xxxx","xxxxx", $mysqli);
$this->assertFalse($NoUserExists);
}

protected function tearDown(){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db'); 
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id IN (200, 201)");
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM members WHERE id IN (200, 201)");
}
}
?>
```

Any concrete simple solutions that don't require much refactoring or time? This is the code snippet that I don't want to keep writing within each function:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `global` keyword in your `setUp()` function.  Like this:

```
global $mysqli;
```

You can then use:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrname', 'password', 'db');
```

As a global variable.

Comment: I tried that and took away the database declaration within each function however I get an error message: "Call to a member function query() on a non-object" and it complains about my tearDown function. THen I added the global $mysqli and the declaration in the tearDown function and then I get the exakt same error message that I usually get: "Undefined variable mysqli" in my test functions. Or do you mean that I also need to add: global $mysqli within each function?

Comment: Have you tried printing each `var` to make sure they are not empty?

Comment: When I try to echo the $mysqli it says: "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"